r summary table for discrete and continuous variables
My apologies if this question is a duplicate or asked somewhere already.
I like to create summary tables with this format.
1) Discrete variables    : n/N (%)
2a) Continuous variables : mean (SD); N
2b) Continuous variables : median (IQR); N

For example if this is my data
# Example dataset
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  ChildSex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 5006, replace = TRUE),
  col1 = rnorm(5006, mean = 300, sd = 100),
  col2 = rnorm(5006, mean = 400, sd = 150),
  col3 = rnorm(5006, mean = 470, sd = 200)
)

The expected summary should appear like this
Discrete Variables                                   
Child sex                                      
   Male                             2505/5006 (50%)
   Female                           2501/5006 (50%)
   Data missing                     0   /5006 (0%)

Continuous Variables: mean (SD); N
   Col1                            299.90 (99.38); 5006
   Col2                            399.12 (151.530); 5006
Continuous Variables: median (IQR); N
   Col3                            465.85 (268.15); 5006

I have around 20 discrete variables and 30 continuous variables (18 mean,sd and 12 median, IQR). I like to create a summary table as shown above without having to enter the variable names or levels manually. Thankful for any suggestions or advise in advance..

You could get most of this (in different format) from Hmisc::describe(data). Or perhaps summarytools::dfSummary(data)

tbl_summary from gtsummary gets you close too.

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  ChildSex = c(sample(c("Male", "Female"), 5005, replace = TRUE), NA),
  col1 = rnorm(5006, mean = 300, sd = 100),
  col2 = rnorm(5006, mean = 400, sd = 150),
  col3 = rnorm(5006, mean = 470, sd = 200)
)

data

    tbl_summary(data,
                type=list(all_continuous()~"continuous2"),
                statistic = list(c(col1,col2) ~ "{mean} ({sd}); {N_nonmiss}", 
                                 col3 ~ "{median} ({p25}-{p75}); {N_nonmiss}",
                                 all_categorical() ~"{n}/{N_nonmiss} ({p}%)"),
                digits=list(all_continuous()~c(2, 2, 0, 0)),
                missing="ifany",
                missing_text = "Data missing",
                missing_stat = "{N_miss} / {N_obs} ({p_miss}%))")

Gives


HI Ed, for some reason i am getting this error
Error in gtsummary::tbl_summary(data, type = list(col1 = "continuous2",  :    unused argument (missing_stat = "{N_miss} / {N_obs} ({p_miss}%))")

I think you need to update the gtsummary version. missing_stat may have been a recent addition. update.packages("gtsummary")

ah yes, you are right. That worked after updating the library. How do I update this line c(col1,col2) ~ "{mean} ({sd}) to include sample size n. I tried this c(col1,col2) ~ "{mean} ({sd}) {n}" and it did not work. I got and error.

that will work. Thanks a ton.
